# How I can specify SMTP account on wp_mail function?

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

I am developin a web site based in wordpress and we have Easy SMTP plugin configured with an SMTP account.

In adiction, I'm coding a plugin to this site. I need all emails been sended from one account, except the emails sended by my plugin.

Theese emails must have another sender (other smtp account). Both SMTP accounts will be in the same SMTP server.

Is this possible? Can I pass some header to wp_mail function to change the SMTP authentication account for a specific email send?

I don't see any documentation that helps me...

Thanks.

edit:
I know that I can do something like:

```
$cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <cumples@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

But i'm not sure that if this is a good method or if is recomendable doing it.

Comment: The settings SMTP and smtp_port (default: 25) need to be set in your php.ini file

Comment: You have to put SMTP details in your php.ini.

Comment: In php.ini can be more than one SMTP configuration?

Comment: No, you can't @msolla

Comment: That's my question, I need that all emails have one sender, except my plugins emails, that must have other.